# about tables linking in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table t1 in sql with following fields (id,s_name)

```
id   s_name
1    priya
2    radhika 
3    aniket
4    abhiskek
```

and another table t2 with following fields

```
(id,s_name,guide)

id   s_name   guide
1    priya    Mr.XYZ
4    abhishek Mr.ABC
```

I want to form a single table joining these both as follow

```
id   s_name   guide
1    priya    Mr.XYZ
2    radhika  NULL
3    aniket   NULL
4    abhishek Mr.ABC
```

Please help me find out an appropriate SQL QUERY for the above

Comment: You can use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I used it,but could not find an appropriate condition for joining.It either shows duplicate records or shows the record of t2 only..

Comment: Please suggest a query that will work correct on my problem.

Comment: @kritiupadhyay can u check my answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([id] int, [s_name] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([id], [s_name])
VALUES
    (1, 'priya'),
    (2, 'radhika'),
    (3, 'aniket'),
    (4, 'abhiskek')
;
CREATE TABLE #Table122
    ([id] int, [s_name] varchar(8), [guide] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO #Table122
    ([id], [s_name], [guide])
VALUES

    ('1', 'priya', 'Mr.XYZ'),
    ('4', 'abhishek', 'Mr.ABC')
;
select a.id,a.s_name,guide from #Table1 A left join 
#Table122 B on a.id=b.id
```

output

```
id  s_name       guide
1   priya        Mr.XYZ
2   radhika      null
3   aniket       NULL
4   abhiskek    Mr.ABC
```

Comment: Your query worked well.However ,another issue that I am facing right now is, when I am entering the value in table via a user interface(forms) it's resulting in an error i.e invalid object name (#tablename).Can you help in this reference .The language I am working on is C#,ASP.NET.

Comment: @kritiupadhyay i dont know c#asp.net i know only SQL

Comment: Okay...No problem..Thanks for your help... :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT a.id, a.s_name, b.guide
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id`